# is it possible to add a template tag to a form field in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
{{ form.my_field|my_template_tag }}
```

I want to manipulate the value of a form input.  This seemed like a logical way to do so.

When I tried this, I got the error:

> cannot concatenate 'str' and 'BoundField' objects

Is it possible?

Comment: As form fields are actually instances of a Field class, this is not going to work out well. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I need to round a field value.  What do you suggest?

Comment: You need to round a field value in the _input_? So if the user enters `123.56` you want to show `124` in the form?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not tested

```
{% if form.my_field.value %}
{{ form.my_field.value|my_template_tag }}
{% endif %}
```